# python master/child looping unintentionally

Tags: python, sockets, windows-7, python-3.x, subprocess

Problem:  I expect child to time out and be done.  but instead it times out and begins to run again.

Can anyone tell me why this program runs forever?  I expect it to run one time and exit...

Here is a working program.  Master threads a function to spawn a child.  Works great except it ends up looping.

Here is the master:

```
# master.py
import multiprocessing, subprocess, sys, time

def f():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Python32\\python.exe", "child.py"])
    # wait until child ends and check exit code
    while p.poll() == None:
        time.sleep(2)
    if p.poll() != 0:
        print("something went wrong with child.py")

# multithread a function process to launch and monitor a child
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = f())
p1.start()
```

and the child:

```
# child.py
import socket, sys

def main(args):
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.settimeout(10)
        sock.bind(('', 54324))
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        print(data)
        sock.close()
        return 0
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        try:
            sock.close()
            return 0
        except:
            return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: You use `target=f()`...it should just be `target=f`.

Comment: When I do that my Program runs continuously producing [errno 10048] (socket in use) scrolling as fast as it can... and when I stop it using ctrl+c I got 15 lines of "Keyboard Interupt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `master.py` doesn't have an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard. On Windows, `multiprocessing` has to be able to reimport the `main` module in the child process, and if you don't use this `if` guard, you will re-execute the `multiprocessing.Process` in the child (resulting in an accidental forkbomb).

To fix, simply put all of the commands in `master.py` in the `if` guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # multithread a function process to launch and monitor a child
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = f())
    p1.start()
```

Comment: If I remove `sock.settimeout(10)` from my child, when I exit using ctrl+c I get [errno 10048] the next time I run the program. Why does the try statement not handle that well?  I need a way to exit this program without locking my socket.

Comment: If you remove the timeout, `sock.recvfrom` blocks forever. If you somehow leave a child alive somewhere, it will hold on to the socket forever. Check to see that all your `child` processes are dead.

Comment: yes!  i have 2 python.exe(s) in my task manager.  How can I terminate my child processes on exit of my master?